# Why does this multiplication cause an OverflowException?

Tags: vb.net, exception, overflow, multiplication

My code tries to multiply 12303 by 174596.

Any decent calculator is capable of providing an answer to this, so why do I get an OverflowException? It also happens when I execute it directly in the Immediate Window.

The code is meant to determine the position of a certain value in a binary file. The file itself is 7 Gb in size.

Is there any way to solve this?

```
Dim position As Long = hisFileHeader.StreamStartDataPosition + 
  (TSIdx * hisFileHeader.StreamDataBlockSize)
```

`tsidx` has a value of 12303 and `StreamDataBlockSize` has a value of 174596

[image: screenshot]

Comment: some code and where it breaks would help

Comment: code language ?

Comment: written in VB.Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that `tsidx` and `StreamDataBlockSize` are `Integer` types. The largest number an `Integer` type can hold is 2,147,483,647. The multiplication in brackets is then done expecting an integer result, but the answer is out of the range of `Integer` types. Change your code to ..

```
Dim position As Long = hisFileHeader.StreamStartDataPosition + (CLng(TSIdx) * hisFileHeader.StreamDataBlockSize)
```

and the multiplication will be done with the expectation of a `Long` type.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If an answer sorts out your problem, don't forget to click the tick next to the answer - It makes sure that the user gets reputation points and makes it easier for anyone else who has the same problem to see that your question has an accepted answer that might work for them as well. (And the person answering the question gets reputation points btw) I'm not being a points addict, but it's a good habit to get into.